# PHP to MySQL Code problems

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I know there a lot of questions on MySQL and PHP but I can't seem to find an answer simple enough for me to understand what to do **and** why.

Here is my form script

```
<form name="tickets" action="tickets98829849.php" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
Number of Tickets: <input type="text" name="quant"><br><br>
First and Last Name of Date: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
Date a guest? <input type="checkbox" name="guest" value="Yes">Yes<br><br>
Amount paid per ticket: <br><br>
$<input type="text" name="amount" size="2"><br>
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

and here is my PHP script

```
    <?php

define('DB_NAME', 'ticketpurch');
define('DB_USER', 'dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpsswd');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqlerror());
}
$db_selectd = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqlerror());
}

$value1 = $_POST['firstname']
$value2 = $_POST['lastname']
$value3 = $_POST['quant']
$value4 = $_POST['datename']
$value5 = $_POST['guest']
$value6 = $_POST['amount']

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ticketpurch (firstname, lastname, quant, datename, guest, amount) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
$result = mysql_query($sql)

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
>
```

When I use the form, the data does not get entered into the table. I do not get an error message. What is wrong with it for not letting me access the table and insert data? I am very new to php, so

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: FYI, you are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Try using form method = post rather than get

Comment: If this is your full code you didnt store table name at $table variable.

Comment: First use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get any PHP errors (there is a `;` missing after the query e.g.), second use `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to get SQL errors in your query

Answer (score 1):

Your form's submit method is get but you receive post method. Change it.

Answer (score 0):

In form you mention `method="get"`  change it  to `method="post"`

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $table from the statement. I'm assuming the correct table is ticketpurch, so all you did with $table was confuse the database. In addition, the other answers are also correct. Your form's method is "get," yet you're using $_POST to try to get the data. You should change the form to post, because get is incredibly insecure, especially if this involves purchases.

In addition, you're using deprecated functions like mysql_connect. Instead, use the PDO object. Instead of mysql_connect(), try this:

```
$table = "mytable";
$sql = new PDO;
$sql->__construct(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$stmnt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ticketpurch (firstname, lastname, quant, datename, guest, amount) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
$sql->execute($stmnt);
```

That will ensure that your statements are better secured against SQL injection.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="tickets" action="tickets98829849.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
Number of Tickets: <input type="text" name="quant"><br><br>
First and Last Name of Date: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
Date a guest? <input type="checkbox" name="guest" value="Yes">Yes<br><br>
Amount paid per ticket: <br><br>
$<input type="text" name="amount" size="2"><br>
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

**tickets98829849.php code**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'ticketpurch');
define('DB_USER', 'dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpsswd');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqlerror());
}
$db_selectd = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqlerror());
}

$value1 = $_POST['firstname']
$value2 = $_POST['lastname']
$value3 = $_POST['quant']
$value4 = $_POST['datename']
$value5 = $_POST['guest']
$value6 = $_POST['amount']

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ticketpurch (firstname, lastname, quant, datename, guest, amount) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
$result = mysql_query($sql)

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
>
```

If you use `method="get"` in the `form`,then receive html values using `$_GET['html element name']`;.But for security purpose ,we generally  use `method="post"` in `html` code and receive value in `action` page using `$_POST[];`.